# In-App Purchase: Purchase items on same device using multiple Apple Id

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I am implementing In-App Purchase in my app and test around the existing apps to get some ideas. But I found a scenario which I am quite confused on it.

I have installed an iOS app and purchased the enhanced levels. Later I uninstall this app, sign out from existing iTunes store account and sign in again with another apple id, then reinstall that app again (same app). I found that I no need to purchase again the enhanced levels and I am free to use these enhanced levels although I have reinstall it using another different apple id. I am quite confused on it... so is the purchased items tied on device if we use multiple apple ids on same device?

I understand that I can restore my purchased items on different devices using same apple id. But how about multiple apple id on multiple devices? If I have 2 apple id associated on an device, I use one of them purchased item, but later I use these 2 apple id login to another device, am I still need to pay again to download items I have purchased on previous device?

Please let me know if my scenario and questions are not clear... I hope someone can give some idea on sharing purchased items against different devices and multiple apple ids.

Any suggestions and comments are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you storing app update as a result of purchase (file, NSUserDefaults, keychain, ...) ? What verification are you doing of the IAP response from Apple servers ?

Comment: I've noticed that iOS doesn't always clean up the sandbox completely when you uninstall an app, so any data you've got stored away to tell your program what things have been purchased may linger unexpectedly.  Restart your device and check your app's sandbox to make sure everything's gone.

Answer (score 0):

When the particular app starts up, it has to make a decision about which inApp purchases apply to you.  This could be done is several ways, of which a few are:

1) Check the app file system to see whether certain files exist that correspond to the inApp purchases or whether certain fields in certain app files have certain app-dependent values that say that the inApp purchase applies to you.

In this case, you'll just have exactly the same inApp purchases as the last time the game was played on the device.

2) Check key rings on the device to see whether some indication is there that the inApp purchase was made.  I'm not entirely sure, but in this case I think the keyring would depend on the last person that was "logged in" to the device.  The part I'm not sure about is whether that login would have been to iCloud, the iTunesStore, the most recent login to either of those, or something else.  (I'd appreciate clarification from someone.)

3) Check iCloud for a particular app-dependent key or keys that would then be interpreted in some app-dependent way.  This, of course, depends on iCloud being enabled, so if this is the first method the app uses, it would probably have a fallback as well.

4) If the app has its own login and/or connects you with a login to Facebook or similar, it could use that login to check against its own app server to see which app purchases you should have.

So I would say it all depends on how the particular app is programmed.  The Apple guidelines may put some restrictions on these choices.  (I'd appreciate clarification on that, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Apple only ask you to make purchases of a user available on every device he owns based on his apple id.

Other scenarios is up to you. As what the app. you tested did.